# Give Stream of string and get list of objects matching string using stream and map function in java

Tags: java, spring

I have a map which consists of key as code. I need to pass these map objects and retrieve products which matches this code. I achieved this scenario using loops but I want to know how to implement same using stream and map in java.

code implemented using loops:

```
List<ProductModel> models=new ArrayList<>();    
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry:entries)
        {
            ProductModel product=getProductService().getProductForCode(entry.getValue());
            models.add(product);
        }
```

Please help me in implementing above logic using map and streams in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use collect function of stream something like below, entry is your original map which has String as key & value:

```
List<ProductModel> models= entry.values().stream().
                collect(ArrayList<ProductModel>::new, (x, y) -> x.add(getProductService().
                        getProductForCode(y)), ArrayList::addAll);
```

Or alternatively :

```
List<ProductModel> models=
          entry.values().stream().map(x -> getProductService().getProductForCode(x)).
          collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below code will helps

```
List<ProductModel> models = entry.values().stream().map(getProductService()::getProductForCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
```